# add text to an asp.net textbox control with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

Within an web form I have a some input fields

```
<div id="search1">
        <div class="forminput">
            Label 1<br />
            <input type="text" name="Field1" value="" size="20" />
        </div>
        <div class="forminput">
            Label 2<br />
            <input type="text" name="Field2" value="" size="20" />
        </div>
</div>
```

As focus is lost on the control the value entered needs to be returned to an asp.net textbox control. I have been able to pass the values to a div layer or standard html element using the following code:

```
    function fieldUpdate() {

            var currentValue = $(this).val();
            var field = $(this).attr("name");

                if (currentValue != "") {
                    $("#results").append(field + ":" + currentValue + "+");
                }
        }
 $(function () {
            $("#search1 :input[type=text]").focusout(fieldUpdate);

        });
```

However this does not seem to work with an asp.net server side control. 
**Update**
The objective of this question is to provision the values entered into standard html input fields into an asp:textbox control

```
<asp:TextBox ID="results2" Text="" Width="400" runat="server" />
```

**Update**
Below is a screenshot of how the current solution works. At the top you see teh input fields as a user enters a value and tabs out of each field this value is added to a Div layer labeled results. What I want to do is instead of adding the fieldname and value to a DIV element I want them to instead be added to a asp:textbox control.

[image]

It is preferred to have this code stored within an external js file vs within the aspx page.

Can anyone provide any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

thanks in advance

**Update Solution**
Thanks to James for helping me work though this. Below is the jQuery code as used in the current implementation.

```
function fieldUpdate() {

            var currentValue = $(this).val();
            var field = $(this).attr("name");
            var txt = $("#<%=results2.ClientID%>");
                if (currentValue != "") {
                    $("#results").append(field + ":" + currentValue + "+");
                    if (txt) {
                        txt.val(txt.val() + field + ":" + $(this).val() + "+");
                    }
                }
        }


        $(function () {
        //only evaluate input text field
            $("#search1 :input[type=text]").focusout(fieldUpdate);
```

This will now allow an asp:textbox to be populated with the input field name and value. 
Example Field1:foo+Field2:somevalue2+Field3:somevalue3 ...

Comment: Can you add the HTML that the server side control creates ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem: getting the values out the input fields, or setting the values to the ASP.NET Textbox Control? If it is the last, where is the Textbox Control?

Comment: @Pbirkoff the issue I am having is I need the ability to provision the values from the html input fields into an asp:textbox control. I have updated the question for clarity

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those are not ASP.NET TextBox controls; they're HTML text inputs. To answer your question though, you would do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#input1").val("Hello world");
    });
</script>
<input type="text" id="input1" />
```

I noticed that you're setting the name instead of the ID in your example. I would use ID if you have a choice, but you can find an element by name like this:

```
$("input[name='Field1']").val("Hello world");
```

If you use an actual ASP.NET TextBox control, the solution will be a little different:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").val("Hello world");
    });
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
```

If you want to get all of the text inputs in the `search1` div, you can do this:

```
$(".forminput input[type='text']").val("Hello world!");
```

Here's a jsFiddle for the above example: http://jsfiddle.net/DWYTR/

**EDIT**

Per your comment, here is how you can copy a value from one input to another on `blur`:

```
$(".forminput input[type='text']").blur(function(){
    var txt = $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>");
    if (txt){
        txt.val(txt.val() + $(this).val());
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes you are correct James. the controls are standard html input controls they need to provision an asp.net control so you are correct I am going from input to asp:textbox. Sorry for not being more clear of that in the question

Comment: I used name as I also wanted to append the field name with the value. You suggested using ID over name any reason or just personal preference.  thank you

Comment: It's up to you, but ID is the norm in most cases.

Comment: James I tried your solution but it only adds one value. I need to tab through each field and append the value into the text field. So that it builds a string. (Field1:Value+Field2:value....) I tried using append() but that did not seem to work. Using val only places one value in the text field any suggestions.

Comment: Just updated the last example. Noticed that you have a `forminput` class around the inputs.

Comment: In you last example you demonstrate how to populate all input fields with one value. That is not what I need to do. I want to type a value into a field and when I tab out of that field have the value added to the asp.net textbox file. Val only set the value once it does not append multiple values into the field.  I appreciate your help .

Comment: So you type into one input, and when you tab out of the input it copies the value into another input?

Comment: not the other input fields just the one asp:textbox field. In the example above I want the value that is typed into each html input field to be added to the asp.net textbox contol when once the user tabs out of the input field. I have updated the question to visually represent this.

Comment: Thanks for the help and suggestions James. I omitted the blur and left it on a focus out event I updated the question to show the final implementation.