# .net TextBox control not triggering Datepicker widget

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker

Researched adding text/date to asp.net textbox control via JQuery and found this solution:
[add text to an asp.net textbox control with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081469/add-text-to-an-asp-net-textbox-control-with-jquery)
however it doesn't work as stated

the control may be several layers deep in other controls? I have an old javascript link that seemed to point to: `aspnetForm.ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_TextBox911` but not sure if this applies to JQuery ?

ASPX:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox911" runat="server">
            </asp:TextBox><br />
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#<%=TextBox911.ClientID%>').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: unavailable
  });
});
```

also tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#"+'<%=TextBox911.ClientID%>').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: unavailable
  });
});
```

Master Page contains:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

error:

```
`Compiler Error Message: BC30451: Name 'TextBox911' is not declared.`
```

Comment: Set a class to the control and attach the DatePicker using this class instead of using an ID. `<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox911" runat="server" CssClass="datePicker"></asp:TextBox>` ... `$('.datePicker').datepicker()`

Answer (score 1):

Your textbox `TextBox911` appears to be inside another control such as a repeater or grid. This means the framework will generate ids dynamically at runtime. You can't refer to such a control by its id.

To see the difference, move your textbox outside any other controls, so it's on its own inside the `Form`, and you'll find it works.

Comment: how can I locate it where it is? I need it to stay within the controls

Comment: tried: ` <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox911" class="myTextBox" runat="server">
                </asp:TextBox><br />` with: ` $(".myTextBox").datepicker()` still not working... am I missing something else?

Comment: Create a tiny project with nothing else in it, and the code you've posted will work, both by id and by class.

Comment: yes you are correct, however I was looking for a way to retrieve the ID from within the layers of controls. The use of adding a class to each control does works however I have hundreds of controls I didn't want to have to change.

Comment: @BarclayVision aside from adding a class, are there any other, existing criteria that distinguish the textboxes you're after from all the other textboxes on the page?